# Subcategories in segmented pager are not loading correctly

Tags: swift, pager

[image: App image]

I have implemented MXSegmentedPager, to scroll through the different segments of subcategories. I have nine categories with associated subcategories displayed in segmented pager. For example: when I scroll to index 7, the subcategories of index 0 are showing. Then afterwards when I scroll to index 7, different subcategories are loaded. Here is my code -

```
func segmentedPager(_ segmentedPager: MXSegmentedPager, viewForPageAt index: Int) -> UIView {
         let page = segmentedPager.pager.dequeueReusablePage(withIdentifier: pageId) as! CustomView


         if let category = categoriesArray?[index]{
             page.category = category
         }
         return page
    }
```

I am making API call in viewWillAppear and reloading the segmented pager when data appears.

```
CategoriesApiManager.getCategories { (result) in
            switch result{
            case .success(let data):
                self.categoriesArray = data
                self.segmentedPager.reloadData()

            case .failure(let err):
                print(err)
            }
        }
```

I could not find any solution anywhere. Please help

Comment: could you please add screenshot of your UI?

Comment: @iVarun please check image